# Splitting numpy array into blocks

Tags: python, numpy, block

I've got a 900 x 650 2D numpy array which I'd like to split into 10 x 10 blocks, which will be checked for nonzero elements. Is there a Pythonic way that I can achieve this with numpy?

I'm looking for functionality similar to the following:

```
blocks_that_have_stuff = []
my_array = getArray()
my_array.cut_into_blocks((10, 10))
for block_no, block in enumerate(my_array):
    if numpy.count_nonzero(block) > 5:
        blocks_that_have_stuff.append(block_no)
```

Comment: you mean `numpy.count_nonzero(block) > 5` ?

Comment: Oops, yup that is what I meant.

Comment: how are your blocks supposed to be set up? is it all possible 10x10 blocks? Just non-overlapping 10x10 blocks.

Comment: Non-overlapping 10x10 blocks.

Comment: This stackoverflow answer seems to contain a nice way of splitting a mtrix into blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078155/204218

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a routine that cut your matrix in blocks. The example is very easy to understand. I wrote it in an easy form to display the result (only for checking purpose). If you are interested in it, you could include in the output the number of blocks or anything.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def cut_array2d(array, shape):
    arr_shape = np.shape(array)
    xcut = np.linspace(0,arr_shape[0],shape[0]+1).astype(np.int)
    ycut = np.linspace(0,arr_shape[1],shape[1]+1).astype(np.int)
    blocks = [];    xextent = [];    yextent = []
    for i in range(shape[0]):
        for j in range(shape[1]):
            blocks.append(array[xcut[i]:xcut[i+1],ycut[j]:ycut[j+1]])
            xextent.append([xcut[i],xcut[i+1]])
            yextent.append([ycut[j],ycut[j+1]])
    return xextent,yextent,blocks

nx = 900; ny = 650
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,nx), np.linspace(-5,5,ny))
arr = X**2+Y**2

x,y,blocks = cut_array2d(arr,(10,10))

n = 0

for x,y,block in zip(x,y,blocks):
    n += 1
    plt.imshow(block,extent=[y[0],y[1],x[0],x[1]],
               interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',
               vmin = arr.min(), vmax=arr.max(),
               cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)
    plt.text(0.5*(y[0]+y[1]),0.5*(x[0]+x[1]),str(n),
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center')

plt.xlim([0,900])
plt.ylim([0,650])
plt.savefig("blocks.png",dpi=72)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

Regards

Note: I think you could optimize this routine using np.meshgrid instead a lot of appends with the xextent & yextent.

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could rep you more for this incredible answer.

Comment: @DanDoe, I believe that you can start a bounty (2 days after you posted) on your question, and award it to the above answer.