# Access all elements at given x, y position in 3-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
mat_a = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_b = np.random.random((5, 5))
mat_c = np.random.random((5, 5))
bigmat = np.stack((mat_a, mat_b, mat_c)) # this is a 3, 5, 5 array

for (x, y, z), value in np.ndenumerate(bigmat):
    print (x, y, z)
```

In the example above, how can I loop so that I iterate only across the 5 x 5 array and at each position I get 3 values i.e. loop should run 25 times and each time, I get an array with 3 values (one from each of mat_a, mat_b and mat_c)

- EDIT: Please note that I need to be able to access elements by position later i.e. if `bigmat` is reshaped, there should be a way to access element based on specific y, z

Comment: Do a search for ```python numpy moving sliding rolling window```.  You can find ready mde solutions with scikit-image (view_as_windows) and scikit-learn (extract_patches).

Comment: Here's a way to iterate 25 times with `ndenumerate`: `[bigmat[:,y,z] for (y,z),v in np.ndenumerate(bigmat[0,...])]`

Comment: The function at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174906/2823755) creates an array that produces windows to your spec during iteration.  What is the shape of your actual data?

Comment: @wwii, the shape of my data is 2160 * 4320. When 3 such arrays are combined, the resulting shape is 3 * 2160 * 4320

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function that generates all indices for a given shape, `ndindex`.

```
for y,z in np.ndindex(bigmat.shape[1:]):
    print(y,z,bigmat[:,y,z])

0 0 [ 0 25 50]
0 1 [ 1 26 51]
0 2 [ 2 27 52]
0 3 [ 3 28 53]
0 4 [ 4 29 54]
1 0 [ 5 30 55]
1 1 [ 6 31 56]
...
```

For a simple case like this it isn't much easier than the double `for range` loop.  Nor will it be faster; but you asked for an iteration.

Another iterator is `itertools.product(range(5),range(5))`

Timewise, product is pretty good:

```
In [181]: timeit [bigmat[:,y,z] for y,z in itertools.product(range(5),range(5
     ...: ))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.5 µs per loop

In [191]: timeit [bigmat[:,y,z] for (y,z),v in np.ndenumerate(bigmat[0,...])]
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.9 µs per loop
```

transposing and reshaping is the fastest way to get a list (or array) of the triplets - but it does not give the indices as well:

```
In [198]: timeit list(bigmat.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop
```

But the same operation gets the indices from `np.mgrid` (or `np.meshgrid`):

```
np.mgrid[0:5,0:5].transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,2)
```

(though this is surprisingly slow)

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, will it be faster when array size is 2160 * 4320?

Comment: I don't think there's much difference in iterative methods.  Usually when iterating the action during each iteration is as expensive, if not more so, than the iteration itself.  Doing something 4000 times is expensive, regardless of the iteration method.

Answer (score 2):

Simon's answer is fine. If you reshape things properly you can get them all in a nice array without any looping.

```
In [33]: bigmat
Out[33]: 
array([[[ 0.51701737,  0.90723012,  0.42534365,  0.3087416 ,  0.44315561],
        [ 0.3902181 ,  0.59261932,  0.21231607,  0.61440961,  0.24910501],
        [ 0.63911556,  0.16333704,  0.62123781,  0.6298554 ,  0.29012245],
        [ 0.95260313,  0.86813746,  0.26722519,  0.14738102,  0.60523372],
        [ 0.33189713,  0.6494197 ,  0.30269686,  0.47312059,  0.84690451]],

       [[ 0.95974972,  0.09659425,  0.06765838,  0.36025411,  0.91492751],
        [ 0.92421874,  0.31670119,  0.99623178,  0.30394588,  0.30970197],
        [ 0.53590091,  0.04273708,  0.97876218,  0.09686119,  0.78394054],
        [ 0.5463358 ,  0.29239676,  0.6284822 ,  0.96649507,  0.05261606],
        [ 0.91733464,  0.77312656,  0.45962704,  0.06446105,  0.58643379]],

       [[ 0.75161903,  0.43286354,  0.09633492,  0.52275049,  0.40827006],
        [ 0.51816158,  0.05330978,  0.49134325,  0.73652136,  0.14437844],
        [ 0.83833791,  0.2072704 ,  0.18345275,  0.57282927,  0.7218022 ],
        [ 0.56180415,  0.85591746,  0.35482315,  0.94562085,  0.92706479],
        [ 0.2994697 ,  0.99724253,  0.66386017,  0.0121033 ,  0.43448805]]])
```

Reshaping things...

```
new_bigmat =  bigmat.T.reshape([25,3])

In [36]: new_bigmat
Out[36]: 
array([[ 0.51701737,  0.95974972,  0.75161903],
       [ 0.3902181 ,  0.92421874,  0.51816158],
       [ 0.63911556,  0.53590091,  0.83833791],
       [ 0.95260313,  0.5463358 ,  0.56180415],
       [ 0.33189713,  0.91733464,  0.2994697 ],
       [ 0.90723012,  0.09659425,  0.43286354],
       [ 0.59261932,  0.31670119,  0.05330978],
       [ 0.16333704,  0.04273708,  0.2072704 ],
       [ 0.86813746,  0.29239676,  0.85591746],
       [ 0.6494197 ,  0.77312656,  0.99724253],
       [ 0.42534365,  0.06765838,  0.09633492],
       [ 0.21231607,  0.99623178,  0.49134325],
       [ 0.62123781,  0.97876218,  0.18345275],
       [ 0.26722519,  0.6284822 ,  0.35482315],
       [ 0.30269686,  0.45962704,  0.66386017],
       [ 0.3087416 ,  0.36025411,  0.52275049],
       [ 0.61440961,  0.30394588,  0.73652136],
       [ 0.6298554 ,  0.09686119,  0.57282927],
       [ 0.14738102,  0.96649507,  0.94562085],
       [ 0.47312059,  0.06446105,  0.0121033 ],
       [ 0.44315561,  0.91492751,  0.40827006],
       [ 0.24910501,  0.30970197,  0.14437844],
       [ 0.29012245,  0.78394054,  0.7218022 ],
       [ 0.60523372,  0.05261606,  0.92706479],
       [ 0.84690451,  0.58643379,  0.43448805]])
```

Edit: To keep track of indices, you might try the following (open to other ideas here). Each row in `xy_index` gives your x,y values respectively for the corresponding row in the `new_bigmat` array. This answer doesn't require any loops. If looping is acceptable you can borrow Simon's suggestion in the comments or `np.ndindex` as suggested in hpaulj's answer.

```
row_index, col_index = np.meshgrid(range(5),range(5))
xy_index = np.array([row_index.flatten(), col_index.flatten()]).T

In [48]: xy_index
Out[48]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: Excellent tip. I agree this is the best approach for many circumstances.

Comment: thanks @user2241910, this looks like a great answer. One issue though, and I have clarified that now in my question. I need to fill in a new array based on the position elements y and z. Since you reshape the array, how do I get those?

Comment: Or the correct row could be accessed by `new_bigmat[x+5*y]`.

Answer (score 1):

The required result can be obtained by slicing, e.g.:

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        print (bigmat[:,x,y])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to stack the arrays, and only want to iterate over all three arrays, element-wise, *at once*, [numpy.nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) works - I'm still fuzzy on all its parameters  I don't know if it is any faster, test it on a subset.

```
a1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) + 10
a2 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) + 20
a3 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) + 30

c = np.nditer((a1, a2, a3))
for thing in c:
    print(np.array(thing))

>>> 
[10 20 30]
[11 21 31]
[12 22 32]
[13 23 33]
[14 24 34]
[15 25 35]
[16 26 36]
[17 27 37]
[18 28 38]
>>>
```