# Finding relative maximums of a 2-D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D numpy array that can be subdivided into 64 boxes (think of a chessboard).
The goal is a function that returns the position and value of the maximum in each box. Something like:

```
FindRefs(array) --> [(argmaxX00, argmaxY00, Max00), ...,(argmaxX63, argmaxY63, Max63)]
```

where *argmaxXnn* and *argmaxYnn* are the indexes of the whole array (not of the box), and *Maxnn* is the max value in each box. In other words,

```
Maxnn = array[argmaxYnn,argmaxYnn]
```

I've tryed the obvious "nested-for" solution:

```
def FindRefs(array):
    Height, Width = array.shape
    plumx = []
    plumy = []
    lum = []
    w = int(Width/8)
    h = int(Height/8)
    for n in range(0,8):    # recorrer boxes
        x0 = n*w
        x1 = (n+1)*w
        for m in range(0,8):
            y0 = m*h
            y1 = (m+1)*h
            subflatind = a[y0:y1,x0:x1].argmax() # flatten index of box
            y, x = np.unravel_index(subflatind, (h, w))
            X = x0 + x
            Y = y0 + y
            lum.append(a[Y,X])
            plumx.append(X)
            plumy.append(Y)

    refs = []
    for pt in range(0,len(plumx)):
        ptx = plumx[pt]
        pty = plumy[pt]
        refs.append((ptx,pty,lum[pt]))
    return refs
```

It works, but is neither elegant nor eficient.
So I've tryed this more pythonic version:

```
def FindRefs(a):
    box = [(n*w,m*h) for n in range(0,8) for m in range(0,8)]
    flatinds = [a[b[1]:h+b[1],b[0]:w+b[0]].argmax() for b in box]
    unravels = np.unravel_index(flatinds, (h, w))
    ur = [(unravels[1][n],unravels[0][n]) for n in range(0,len(box))]
    absinds = [map(sum,zip(box[n],ur[n])) for n in range(0,len(box))]
    refs = [(absinds[n][0],absinds[n][1],a[absinds[n][1],absinds[n][0]]) for n in range(0,len(box))] 
    return refs
```

It works fine but, to my surprise, is not more efficient than the previous version!

The question is: Is there a more clever way to do the task?

Note that efficiency matters, as I have many large arrays for processing.

Any clue is welcome. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I efficiently process a numpy array in blocks similar to Matlab's blkproc (blockproc) function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073767/how-can-i-efficiently-process-a-numpy-array-in-blocks-similar-to-matlabs-blkpro)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as ast
import numpy as np
def FindRefs3(a):
    box = tuple(x/8 for x in a.shape)
    z=ast(a, \
          shape=(8,8)+box, \
          strides=(a.strides[0]*box[0],a.strides[1]*box[1])+a.strides)
    v3 = np.max(z,axis=-1)
    i3r = np.argmax(z,axis=-1)
    v2 = np.max(v3,axis=-1)
    i2 = np.argmax(v3,axis=-1)
    i2x = np.indices(i2.shape)
    i3 = i3r[np.ix_(*[np.arange(x) for x in i2.shape])+(i2,)]
    i3x = np.indices(i3.shape)
    ix0 = i2x[0]*box[0]+i2
    ix1 = i3x[1]*box[1]+i3
    return zip(np.ravel(ix0),np.ravel(ix1),np.ravel(v2))
```

Note that your first FindRefs reverses indices, so that for a tuple (i1,i2,v), a[i1,i2] won't return the right value, whereas a[i2,i1] will.

So here's what the code does:

- It first calculates the dimensions that each box needs to have (`box`) given the size of your array. Note that this doesn't do any checking: you need to have an array that *can* be divided evenly into an 8 by 8 grid.
- Then `z` with `ast` is the messiest bit. It takes the 2d array, and turns it into a *4d* array. The 4d array has dimensions (8,8,box[0],box[1]), so it lets you choose which box you want (the first two axes) and then what position you want in the box (the next two). This lets us deal with all the boxes at once by doing operations on the last two axes.
- `v3` gives us the maximum values along the last axis: in other words, it contains the maximum of each column in each box. i3r contains the index of which row in the box contained that max value.
- `v2` takes the maximum of `v3` along its own last axis, which is now dealing with rows in the box: it takes the column maxes, and finds the maximum of them, so that `v2` is a 2d array containing the maximum value of each box. **If all you wanted were the maximums, this is all you'd need.**
- `i2` is the index of the column in the box that holds the maximum value.
- Now we need to get the index of the row in the box... that's trickier. `i3r` contains the row index of the max of each column in the box, but we want the row for the specific column that's specified in i2. We do this by choosing an element from `i3r` using `i2`, which gives us `i3`.
- At this point, `i2` and `i3` are 8 by 8 arrays containing the row and column indexes of the maximums relative to each box. We want the absolute indexes. So we create `i2x` and `i3x` (actually, this is pointless; we could just create one, as they are the same), which are just arrays of what the indexes for `i2` and `i3` are (0,1,2,...,8 etc in one dimension, and so on). We then multiply these by the box sizes, and add the relative max indexes, to get the absolute max indexes.
- We then combine these to get the same output that you had. Note that if you keep them as arrays, though, instead of making tuples, it's much faster.

Comment: Note that you don't need backslashes in the call to `ast` since it's surrounded by brackets.

Comment: True - for some reason I tend to obsessively place backslashes everywhere, perhaps worrying that if I don't, I'll forget when I switch to another language that needs them.

Comment: Wow, definitely strides stuff is the key !  I must study Numpy more thoroughly. Meanwhile, I'm trying to understand the logic of your code

Comment: , since the line "    i3 = i2.choose(np.rollaxis(i3r,-1)) " reports: ValueError: Need between 2 and (32) array objects (inclusive).

Comment: Bah - I should have known that undocumented limitation would come up. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28931900/599265 for more info on that point. I'll try to get that the NPY_MAXARGS limitation on np.choose documented, because it's rather annoying to have it suddenly appear. In any case, the modified version is more confusing, but should work.

Comment: ... and I've added an explanation of the code, though it's probably rather confusingly written.

Comment: Thanks @cge  for your detailed answer. It has been very useful, I learned a lot. I am returning the arrays (rather than tuples) and really improves the efficiency and harmony of all the code .